# Fill a TableView with Mysql contents

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I want to fill my tableview with some data that I have in my database mysql! I've no problem to download this data! The problem is that when the view is loaded my data is not yet downloaded from the web so my app crash because array that fill the tableView are still blanks! The question is... How to prevent that the tableViws is filled at start?

Sorry for my english

Comment: That should display a table with no cells rather than crash if you use the same data source for both the count of cells and the cell contents.

Answer (score 0):

If the app crash because your array is blank that probably means that you haven't allocated the array. If the array is just empty, there shouldn't be any problem. In the viewDidLoad method you should start by allocating an empty array, then have a method that downloads the data from the mysql database and add it to this array and as soon as it's done, just do [self.tableView reloadData].

Comment: @user1639377 did this help any?